# How to get package metadata using the dotnet cli?

Tags: command-line, .net-core, nuget-package

I would like to fetch the metadata (packageUrl, licenseinfo, etc.) for each package associated in a project/solution. I can use the [dotnet cli list package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package) command to get the list of packages but it only returns the name of the package. I can [retrieve metadata from within the Package Manager Console within visual studio](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/235082/get-license-information-for-all-used-nuget-packages) but I need to be able to do this outside of visual studio as part of a build requirement.

Is this possible and how can this be done?